# How to update an object from a previous ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller called `searchUpdateController`, it has a button to push a new view controller called editController. In the editController there is a button called Save and it contains the following code:

```
searchUpdateController = [[SearchUpdate alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [searchUpdateController.fieldsValArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:joinedString];
    [searchUpdateController.mainTable reloadData];
    [searchUpdateController release];
```

`fieldsValArray` is a `NSMutableArray` property in `searchUpdateController` and mainTable is the tableView in the `searchUpdateController`. I wanted to update the content of the `fieldsValArray` and reload the data of the tableView. Nothing happens when I click the Save button. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Dont do this -> searchUpdateController = [[SearchUpdate alloc] init];

Here you are creating new object, which is not referring to your older object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating a new objet not using the old one in the code
`searchUpdateController = [[SearchUpdate alloc] init];` set them `searchUpdateController` from `SearchUpdateController` class. so that it point to that object that pushes the `editController`

Comment: hmm there is no effect, i've placed @class SearchUpdate; in my second controller .h file and I've declared a property searchUpdateController,

Comment: have you set like this `editController.searchUpdateController = self` from the `SearchUpdateController` class where you are pushing `editController`

Answer (score 1):

Dont do this -> searchUpdateController = [[SearchUpdate alloc] init];
Here you are creating new object, which is not referring to your older object

Before moving back to *searchUpdateController* do this:

- Get second last object from self.navigationController. viewControllers, which is nothing but the *searchUpdateController*
- Now you are having the same object so update the array data whichever you want
- Now there are two possibilities to reload data:

  1. Use NSNotification and fire a notification to parent view controller where need to reload table
  2. Call a method of parent class which will reload table

Hope this is what you want.